# c# - Is there any way to clone array with value type, without create new reference type?

Tags: c#, python

i'm new to c# with python background.

In python, i can do this way:

```
a = [1, 5, 10] #initialize

a = [1, 3, 5] #change the value
```

How can i perform `a = {1, 3, 5}` on c#? Currently i found this way.

```
int[] a = {1, 5, 10}; //initialize

int[] b = {1 ,3, 5}; //create new reference type

a = (int[])b.Clone(); //change the value
```

Is there any better way to  to change entire array `a` from `{1, 5, 10}` to `{1 ,3, 5}`?

i.e. `a = [1, 3, 5]` on python to C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but surely just...

```
a = new int[]{1, 3, 5};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) (which is zero based)

```
a[2] = 5;
```

If you want to change whole array, then assign a new reference for it, like

```
int[] a = new[] {1, 2, 10};
a = new[] {1,2,5};
```

Your original array will lose all the references to it and become subject to GC. The second line assigns `a` a reference to the new array.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, actually i want to ask how to achieve this goal on c#.

Comment: That is C#, cannot see what's the problem.

Comment: But i want to change entire array from {1, 5, 10} to {1 ,3, 5}, not just one index based on your answer.

Comment: If you want to reassign the array, go with musefan or Romoku answer...If you just want to change the value in specific index, it's the right way.....

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a variable like in python.

When you assign to the variable `a = {1, 5, 10}` it assigns the value of the reference to the array in the variable. This is the shorthand syntax for assigning arrays.

To reassign the variable you simply assign to it again using the `new` operator `a = new[] {1, 5, 5}`.

Sample:

```
int[] a = {1, 5, 10}; // Shorthand syntax for creating array

a = new[] {1, 5, 5}; // Reassign using new operator
```

See [Array initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: It seems that the OP didn't want to make a copy of an existing array, but just to create an entirely new one. But I'll leave this here in case.]

That's the normal way to create a copy of an array that isn't just a reference to the original array.

There is a faster way of doing it, which is to use `Array.Copy()` directly. You can wrap it in an extension method to make it easier to use:

```
/// <summary>Shallow clones an array.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of array elements.</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">An array to clone.</param>
/// <returns>The cloned array.</returns>
/// <remarks>This is much faster than the built-in <see cref="Array.Clone"/> method.</remarks>

public static T[] ShallowClone<T>(this T[] array)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    T[] result = new T[array.Length];
    Array.Copy(array, result, array.Length);
    return result;
}
```

Normally you wouldn't worry about performance, but this does happen to be faster than using `Array.Copy()`.

You can use it like so:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};

int[] b = a.ShallowClone();
```

This way, it's both faster *and* you don't need to cast (although you could of course also write an extension method that used `Array.Clone()`.)